# How to insert a method inside a LINQ lambda extension method

Tags: c#, linq, methods

I have to place a method inside a LINQ lambda. I have the following code:

```
string productName = "Some product";

searchShoppingCart = shoppingCart.Where(m => productName.Equals(_ProductRepository.GetProductName(m.Id)));
```

Basically this code is used to select all the `shoppingCart` instances that contain `productName`.

The method `string GetProductName(int shoppingCartId)` is a method  from `_ProductRepository` that returns the name of one product. How this method is implemented and its logic does not matter.

The problem is that LINQ throws an **exception**. I know the reasons why this exception is thrown, I just would like to know a workaround. I tried

```
var productContained = shoppingCart.Select(sc => new
                    {
                        scId = sc.Id,
                        productName = _ProductRepository.GetProductName(sc.Id)
                    });

searchShoppingCart = shoppingCart.Where(sc => sc.Id.Equals(productContained.Where(pc => pc.productName.Equals(productName))
                                                                           .Select(pc => pc.Id)));
```

but it gives me the same exception. Is there any other workaround?

**UPDATE**

The exception thrown is

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetProductName(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

Comment: I think it's important to know what exception so that others can help you.

Comment: What exception is thrown? Whats the stacktrace?

Comment: "I know the reasons why this exception is thrown" -> somehow I doubt that. But in any case, how can you expect suggestions when you don't even tell us what exception it is?

Comment: sorry I thought everybody was aware that it is not possible to place a custom method/function inside a LINQ lambda. It launches the same exception with ToString(). See the update

Comment: You should query on products in your cart - something like `shoppingCart.ProductsInCart.Where`. If you are searching for a cart that contains a product with `productNam` then your code is smelly and you should use proper naming. 
Also the first code snippet emit a SQL statement searching a product (!) for every item in `shoppingCart` (!) collection.

Comment: why is my code smelly? The GetProductName method is complex and recursive. To make things more clear I could've posted it as well but it isn't within the question's scope

Comment: @CiccioMiami: It is not possible to place a custom method call inside an `Expression<Func>` (i.e. talking to an `IQueryable`). It is *totally* possible to place it inside a `Func` (i.e. talking to an `IEnumerable`). And it is also not possible to know from the code you gave which of the two it is, since you don't give the type of `shoppingCart`.

Answer (score 2):

It throws an exception because it tries to convert your code to SQL (and it can't do it). Read this article for some workarounds: http://thoai-nguyen.blogspot.it/2011/05/custom-function-entity-framework.html

Comment: if that's true, that is only an explanation. A solution would be to use .ToList().

Comment: Convert to a list? If there are a lot of records it may be really expansive. If he isn't sure about database size (or it may increase in the future, I think he wouldn't like to find all ToList). I'd prefer the stored procedure.

Comment: @CiccioMiami don't worry, it's a common exception...we saw that often!

Comment: @FabioMilheiro the solution is in the link. Do that on the database, not in the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

If your are working `IQueryable` (which I believe that you do) then a call to custom .NET method cannot be translated into the query - that's the reason you get exception.

The work-around would be to fetch all possible shopping carts then apply your method on in-memory product list - for example,

```
searchShoppingCart = shoppingCart.ToList().Where(m => productName.Equals(_ProductRepository.GetProductName(m.Id)))
```

Of course, this sucks as it defeats the whole purpose!

Better work-around would be to expose product navigable property within shopping cart object and use the same - for example,

```
searchShoppingCart = shoppingCart.Where(m => productName.Equals(m.Product.Name))
```

Comment: Better to use `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToList`.

Comment: thanks VinayC! Your assumption is correct I would like to use deferred execution as much as I can. The problem with your second snippet is that the GetProductName function is more complex, in the specific it is recursive. Morevoer I avoid to use navigation properties outside the repository in order to keep the components flexible and reusable

Comment: @CiccioMiami, look at spender's suggestion - `AsEnumerable` will differ fetching all shopping carts till needed. If you want to avoid fetching all carts to  memory then you must translate product name computation/comparison to the database layer - there is no other way around! Perhaps, you can move GetProductName implementation to database layer as a view or table value function and map it as `ProductName` entity.

Comment: @VinayC, in short `AsEnumerable()`  uses deferred execution or has a behavior similar to the methods using the `yield`  keyword?

Comment: I tried your solution but populating the object (almost 5000 hits) takes a long time...try to see where is the bottleneck

Comment: @CiccioMiami, which solution - `ToList` or `AsEnumerable`? If yes, fetching all shopping carts will take some time but the most time of time will be spent because GetProductName will operate on row by row basic - i.e. it would translate into multiple database calls (equal to the number of shopping carts). I would rather suggest the other solution - either navigable property or having `ProductName` entity. That way, you will only make one database call.